# How to get char from string

Tags: c, arrays, string

Can I ask why it shows me "Zero" instead of index?

Current output: 0

Expected output: 6

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int index_equal;    
    char array[20] = {"2n+n2n=n4n"};
    for (int j = 0; j > 20; j++) {
        if (array[j] == '=') {
            index_equal = j;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d", index_equal);
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't do anything at all, because the condition of your for loop is wrong (it should be `j<20` not `j>20`)

Comment: @FelixG The `printf` statement is outside the `for` loop, so it's printing an uninitialized value that just happens to be zero.

Comment: @AdrianMole Yeah, just noticed that myself... i was mislead by the indentation

Comment: I assume you mean `0`, not `zero`. In fact it should print any "random" value as you don't initialize `index_equal`

Answer (score 4):

There is problem in for loop you should write j<20 other wise loop will never execute

```
for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
```

This should be right approach

Answer (score 3):

> 1)problem is here

```
  for(int j = 0; j>20; j++)
```

`j>20` it should be `j<20`.

> 2)And there is no need to run the loop for 20 elements instead do this

```
  int len=strlen(array);
```

and

```
  for(int j = 0; j<len; j++)
```

or

```
  for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
```

or

```
   for(int j=0;array[j];j++)
```

> 3)Can I ask why it shows me "Zero" instead of index?

```
  for (int j = 0; j > 20; j++)
```

because value of j is 0 and `j > 20` is false i.e `(0>20)` so the loop does not execute and it prints uninitialized value(index_equal).

Answer (score 2):

J>20 must be j<20 for loop doesnt execute

Answer (score 2):

Solution seems to be misjudged for loop. I am providing enhancement to your code.
You can use `size_t` to make your program more dynamic so that it can calculate size of character array and passing that in your loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int index_equal;    
    char array[20] = {"2n+n2n=n4n"};
    size_t n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (array[j] == '=') {
            index_equal = j;
        }
    }
    printf("\n%d", index_equal);
}
```

Comment: You can upvote and accept my answer if you feel it answers your question adequately

Answer (score 0):

how can i "transfer" all these spaces into char 'n' ?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char array[10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    scanf("%c",&array[i]);  
    }
    int len = strlen(array);
    printf("\nLength of this array is %d\n",len);
    //make from space -->'n'
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(isspace(array[i])==true) // otherwise if(array[i]==' ')..
        {
            array[i]=='n';
        }
    }
    puts(array);
    return 0;
}
```

now i am pretty sure that my loop is in correct format

Comment: for example of input (2 + 2 = 4), output should look like (2n+n2n=n4n);